# Cannot open exe created by cx_freeze

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nltk, exe, cx-freeze

I tried converting my keras and nltk chatbot to exe using cx_freeze. When I clicked on the exe, it gave me the following error:
[Error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGpJT.png)

How can I correct this error?
Also, here's my setup.py code:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"includes": ["tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
name = "NAB",
version = "3",
description = " ",
options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
executables = [Executable("nab3.py", base = base)])
```

Btw, my chatbot code works perfectly fine when i run it seperately.
If anyone knows what this error means and how to correct it, please do help me out.
Thanks in advance:)